# Have JSON data, would like to show with sections in IOS6 app

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-calendar-api

I have retrieved my events from a shared google calendar i IOS, and are displaying them in a tableview. As for right now, they're simplty shown with the event title as the title, and the eventtime as the subtitle. I'd like to use the date (eventtime) as a section header in stead, so that all events on for instance march 31st where shown in a group, with the time as a "right detail"

My code looks like this:

```
@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSArray *events;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //show loader view
    //[HUD showUIBlockingIndicatorWithText:@"Fetching JSON"];


    //make HTTP call
    NSString* searchCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/kao1d80fd2u5kh7268caop11o4%%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json"];

    [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString: searchCall
                                  completion:^(NSDictionary *json, JSONModelError *err) {

                                      //got JSON back
                                      NSLog(@"Got JSON from web: %@", json);

                                      if (err) {
                                          [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                      message:[err localizedDescription]
                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                                            otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
                                          return;
                                      }

                                      //initialize the models
                                      events = [CalendarModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:
                                                json[@"feed"][@"entry"]
                                                ];

                                      if (events) NSLog(@"Loaded successfully models");

                                      //show the videos
                                      [self.tableView reloadData];

                                  }];


}
;

#pragma mark - table methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return events.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CalendarModel* event = events[indexPath.row];


    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSzzz";
    NSDate *gmtDate = [formatter dateFromString: [[event.time objectAtIndex:0] startTime]];


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                           event.title
                           ];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate: gmtDate];


    return cell;
}

@end
```

I have found this code online, but he doesn't get data as JSON, but from an iPhone calendar, i believe.

```
@interface MasterViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *sections;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *sortedDays;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDateFormatter *sectionDateFormatter;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDateFormatter *cellDateFormatter;

- (NSDate *)dateAtBeginningOfDayForDate:(NSDate *)inputDate;
- (NSDate *)dateByAddingYears:(NSInteger)numberOfYears toDate:(NSDate *)inputDate;

@end



@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize sections;
@synthesize sortedDays;
@synthesize sectionDateFormatter;
@synthesize cellDateFormatter;


- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *startDate = [self dateAtBeginningOfDayForDate:now];
    NSDate *endDate = [self dateByAddingYears:1 toDate:startDate];

    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:nil];
    NSArray *events = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:searchPredicate];

    self.sections = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (EKEvent *event in events) 
    {
        // Reduce event start date to date components (year, month, day)
        NSDate *dateRepresentingThisDay = [self dateAtBeginningOfDayForDate:event.startDate];

        // If we don't yet have an array to hold the events for this day, create one
        NSMutableArray *eventsOnThisDay = [self.sections objectForKey:dateRepresentingThisDay];
        if (eventsOnThisDay == nil) {
            eventsOnThisDay = [NSMutableArray array];

            // Use the reduced date as dictionary key to later retrieve the event list this day
            [self.sections setObject:eventsOnThisDay forKey:dateRepresentingThisDay];
        }

        // Add the event to the list for this day
        [eventsOnThisDay addObject:event];
    }

    // Create a sorted list of days
    NSArray *unsortedDays = [self.sections allKeys];
    self.sortedDays = [unsortedDays sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    self.sectionDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.sectionDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [self.sectionDateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    self.cellDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.cellDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [self.cellDateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}


#pragma mark - Date Calculations

- (NSDate *)dateAtBeginningOfDayForDate:(NSDate *)inputDate
{
    // Use the user's current calendar and time zone
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [calendar setTimeZone:timeZone];

    // Selectively convert the date components (year, month, day) of the input date
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:inputDate];

    // Set the time components manually
    [dateComps setHour:0];
    [dateComps setMinute:0];
    [dateComps setSecond:0];

    // Convert back       
    NSDate *beginningOfDay = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    return beginningOfDay;
}

- (NSDate *)dateByAddingYears:(NSInteger)numberOfYears toDate:(NSDate *)inputDate
{
    // Use the user's current calendar
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setYear:numberOfYears];

    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComps toDate:inputDate options:0];
    return newDate;
}


#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.sections count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDate *dateRepresentingThisDay = [self.sortedDays objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *eventsOnThisDay = [self.sections objectForKey:dateRepresentingThisDay];
    return [eventsOnThisDay count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDate *dateRepresentingThisDay = [self.sortedDays objectAtIndex:section];
    return [self.sectionDateFormatter stringFromDate:dateRepresentingThisDay];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"EventTitleCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    NSDate *dateRepresentingThisDay = [self.sortedDays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *eventsOnThisDay = [self.sections objectForKey:dateRepresentingThisDay];
    EKEvent *event = [eventsOnThisDay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = event.title;
    if (event.allDay) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"all day";
    } else {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.cellDateFormatter stringFromDate:event.startDate];
    }
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Is there a way for me to use my json event.startdate as a section header?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would ignore the code you posted second there because its not what you are trying to do.

The part of the code where you set you header and subtitle are these two lines:
   cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",event.title];
   cell.detailTextLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate: gmtDate];

So if you want the heading to be the date, just place it as the cell.textLabel.text value.

Comment: He's talking about section header, not cell title.

Comment: But that doesn't create sections though? I'd like all events from on date to be grouped, but what I have in my date is a weird looking google date like "2013-03-26T20:45:00.0000CET"

Answer (score 0):

So if you are wanting to do sections.

Make sure the number of sections is greater then 1.

Then you might want to take a look at these table methods. Just depending on what your exact case and customization needs are you can change it accordingly.

```
(NSString*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   }

(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
 }

(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)table viewForHeaderInSection:(NsInteger)section{
}
```

I hope this helps. I normally would have an example I just didn't have the most available time currently, but if need be I can provide one.

Take Care :)